Why isn't setup.py working on google colab?
I was trying to use pip install to run MusicVAE on google colab. However, the setup code did not work, returning this error:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
Importing libraries and defining some helper functions...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c66ff70fc982> in <cell line: 27>()
     25 print('Importing libraries and defining some helper functions...')
     26 from google.colab import files
---> 27 import magenta.music as mm
     28 from magenta.models.music_vae import configs
     29 from magenta.models.music_vae.trained_model import TrainedModel

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magenta'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

It seems that the module magenta was not properly installed with pip.
I've seen people have similar problems with python setup.py egg_info and tried upgrading pip and reinstalling setuptools, ez_setup and unroll, but those don't work as well.
